# before and after

Tags: meaning

Novartis places great emphasis on leadership development in its pharmaceutical
business. It offered over 160 leadership development courses in 2003
for approximately 4000 associates worldwide. The courses are a combination
of classroom experience and e-learning **before and after**.

I don't understand what the bold part means. 
Please enlighten me.

Comment: Perhaps those attending a course are expected to do some research, and/or study material provided,  **before** the classroom session and follow it up **afterwards**.

Comment: The past tense of the second sentence, placed between the first and third sentences that are in the present tense, is a poor construction. Not only that, but it makes it impossible to tell if the third sentence is actually talking about the 2003 courses (in the wrong tense) or whatever the current courses are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The courses are a combination of classroom experience and e-learning
>   before and after.

This is badly written. I had to read it three times to understand it.

It means that there is e-learning before the classroom experience and more e-learning after the classroom experience.

A better way to write it might be:

The courses consist of classroom experience with e-learning before and after it.